# CNN - LSTM always predicts the same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, lstm

I am trying to predict a sequence of images. Before I was using only a CNN that took as input these concatenated images, but it didn't give me very good results with some databases.

I am using two types of databases, one takes a single image and classifies it. The other database takes a sequence of images and classifies it. So I use `total_x_test_indexes=tf.expand_dims(total_x_test_indexes, axis=1)` to generalize the model when only classifies one image.

As I saw I could better use a CNN and then apply a LSTM and I saw how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545781/how-to-implement-a-cnn-lstm-using-keras).

But I'm only getting confusion matrices like this, classifying almost everything to a class.

My code is this:

```
inp = Input((None,size_image,size_image,1), ragged=True)

x = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inp)

x = LSTM(25)(x)
size_predictions=len(dicTiposNumbers)
print("tamaño ",size_predictions)
out = Dense(size_predictions)(x)

model = Model(inp, out)

print(model.summary())
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.05)
opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.15)
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
          metrics=['accuracy'])



print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')


total_x_train_indexes=tf.gather(total_x,indices=train)
total_y_train_indexes=tf.gather(total_y,indices=train)
total_x_train_indexes=tf.expand_dims(total_x_train_indexes, axis=1)
print("shape after gather",np.shape(total_x_train_indexes[0]))
history = model.fit(total_x_train_indexes, total_y_train_indexes,
            batch_size=512,
            epochs=5)
```

But I'm getting this and similar with other databases with more classes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your question, determine the network's purpose and input data responsive. I created a simple custom layer telling you that the process layer is nothing than simple calculation at each layer data process output is from convolution layers and the dense layers.

Sample: Improving method is done by compare of input / output and try to expands the effects.

Confusion matrix, he tries to see the effects of overall model training and predict with input data.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMAGE_SIZE = ( 21, 16 ) 
objects_classes = [ 'plane', 'helicopter', 'truck' ]

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyLSTMLayer( tf.keras.layers.LSTM ):
    def __init__(self, units, return_sequences, return_state):
        super(MyLSTMLayer, self).__init__( units, return_sequences=True, return_state=False )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)

def gen():
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        # rescale=1./255,
        # shear_range=0.2,
        # zoom_range=0.2,
        # horizontal_flip=True 
        )
    train_generator = train_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'F:\\temp\\image_catagorize',
        classes=[ 'plane', 'helicopter', 'truck' ],
        target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        color_mode='grayscale',
        class_mode='sparse',    # None  # categorical   # binary    # sparse
        subset='training')

    return train_generator
    
train_generator = gen()
val_generator = train_generator

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.97 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
mycustomlayer = MyLSTMLayer( 64, True, False )

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1], 1 ), name="Input_01Layer"),
    tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4), name="UpSampling2DLayer_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2., name="NormalizationLayer_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6., name="NormalizationLayer_02"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', name="Conv2DLayer_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), name="MaxPooling2DLayer_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', name="Conv2DLayer_02"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="MaxPooling2DLayer_02"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name="Conv2DLayer_03"),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 7 * 11, 64 )),
    ###
    mycustomlayer,
    ###
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name="DenseLayer_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="FlattenLayer_01"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu', name="DenseLayer_02"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, name="DenseLayer_03"),
    
], name="MyModelClassification")

model.summary()


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.000001,
    momentum=0.5,
    nesterov=True,
    name='SGD',
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, batch_size=100, epochs=3, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

PATH = os.path.join('F:\\temp\\image_catagorize\\helicopter', '*.png')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
list_file = []
for file in files.take(20):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tf.io.decode_png( image, channels=1, dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8, name='decode_png' )
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE, method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\temp\\image_catagorize\\plane', '*.png')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
for file in files.take(8):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tf.io.decode_png( image, channels=1, dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8, name='decode_png' )
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE, method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\temp\\image_catagorize\\Truck', '*.png')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
for file in files.take(8):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tf.io.decode_png( image, channels=1, dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8, name='decode_png' )
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE, method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(objects_classes[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample]